# UITableView custom accessoryView appearing only in the last cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to use an custom `accessoryView` for `UITableView`. As `accessorView` I am using an `UIImageView`. The problem I am facing is the `accessoryView` is only appearing in the last row of `UITableView`.

In viewDidLoad I initialized the UIImageView.

```
customAccessory = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 15)];
customAccessory.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_right"];
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I am doing this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyDayCell *cell =(MyDayCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyDayCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *cellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyDayCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [cellArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_guide"];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_media"];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_lives"];
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_ask"];
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_k"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    cell.name.text = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryView = customAccessory;
    return cell;
}
```

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You are using same object `customAccessory` in all cell, so it will show in last cell. Creating accessory view to each cell will solve the issue.

Comment: Yes it does. But why is this happening? Why I can not use same accessoryView for all cell?

Comment: A view can only have one parent. It is not possible to show a single view instance more more than once at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

A view can have only one superview. When you are adding custom view to second cell, it will be removed from first cell. So, create the custom accessory view for each table view cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyDayCell *cell =(MyDayCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyDayCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *cellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyDayCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [cellArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_guide"];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_media"];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_lives"];
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_ask"];
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_k"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    cell.name.text = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *customAccessory = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 15)];
    customAccessory.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_right"];
    cell.accessoryView = customAccessory;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ....
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *cellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyDayCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [cellArray objectAtIndex:0];
        UIImageView *customAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 15)];
        customAccessoryView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_right"];
        cell.accessoryView = customAccessoryView;
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: A view can only be contained in a single parent view's hierarchy. As soon as you add it to a new one, it is removed from the previous one. Here, when you add view to a cell it is being removed from previous cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one instance of `customAccessory`. You should create UIImageView for each cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyDayCell *cell =(MyDayCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyDayCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *cellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyDayCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [cellArray objectAtIndex:0];

        customAccessory = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 15)];
        customAccessory.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_right"];
        cell.accessoryView = customAccessory;

    }

    // Here your code... 
    // An return cell
       return cell;
}
```